# Google Cloud Function multiple domain in CORS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How to enable multiple chosen domain in CORS? I can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) how to enable CORS but it is either a `*` card or just a single domain.

I tried something like below but it did not work

```
if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        # TODO: Restrict Origin
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:8080',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:8080'
    }
    return ('', 204, headers)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't set multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` values: you either get one named origin or `*` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMultipleAllowOriginNotAllowed)).

In this case, you can probably just return `http://localhost`; otherwise, I'd recommend you create a list of allowed origins, check the `Origin` header of the incoming request, and return the correct header.

Comment: Hi Mike, okay I understand